# Модули. Python 3.7.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, модули

В чем разница запуска питоновского файла как скрипта и модульного питоновского проекта для компилятора?
И какое отношение ко всему этому делу имеет папка **pycache** с байт кодом?
Еще интересно зачем создается этот байт код это полностью скомпилированный проект или как?

Comment: Интерпретатор упрощает себе задачу разбора кода созданием этих файлов. И еще: этот вопрос не для сообщества. Это исключительно для самостоятельного разбора.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разница в контексте: файл работает в контексте модуля `__main__`, модуль работает в своем модуле. Разница в чистоте и порядке в коде.

При запуске текстовый код переводится в виртуальный байт код языка, который может исполнить интерпретатор. pycache - это чтоб сто раз этим переводом текста в байты не заниматься и ускорить запуск.

Байт код это не скомпилированный код, скомпилированный исполняет центральный процессор. Этот код исполняется интерпретатором: видит он байт в котором написанна операция сложения - берет переменную и отправляет в скомпилированную функцию сложения.

Comment: У меня созрел вопрос, а тот байт код - это байт код всего проекта в целом или только импортируемых модулей ???

Comment: То есть основной модуль тоже переводится в байт код или нет ???

Comment: @Diareich каждый модуль в отдельном файле в кеше.

Comment: @Diareich основной тоже переаодится, на диск не сбрасывается